# updateQuery then check if the value become less than 0

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a SQL Server table named `store` with 3 columns `IDS, Item_Name, Qunt`. I have vb with option that take from store a value by update statement.

My code is:

```
Dim ADP = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("update Store set Qunt = Qunt - @N_Qunt1 where IDS=@CB1", connection)
ADP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CB1", ComboBox2.SelectedValue)
ADP.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Qunt1", N_Qunt1.Text)

If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    connection.Open()
End If

ADP.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Collection.Close()

Dim ADP1 = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("select * from store where IDS=@CB1", connection)
ADP1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CB1", ComboBox2.SelectedValue)

Dim Ds = New DataSet
ADP1.Fill(Ds)

Dim Dt = Ds.Tables(0)
Dim dr = Dt.Rows(0)

If dr!Qunt < 0 Then
    MsgBox(" الكمية المراد سحبها اكبر من المتواجده بالمخزن ", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "سحب")
    Dim ADP2 = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("update Store set Qunt = Qunt + @N_Qunt1 where IDS=@CB1", connection)
    ADP2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CB1", ComboBox2.SelectedValue)
    ADP2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N_Qunt1", N_Qunt1.Text)

    If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        connection.Open()
    End If

    ADP2.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
    CLEAR_TEXTBOXES(Me)
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox(" تمت سحب الكمية بنجاح ", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "سحب")
End If
```

It works fine but definitely that not professional stuff, the idea of my code that execute the update statement then recall the table and check if the Qunt value become less than 0 the message showing refuse the value of pull and then re add the value to the table, any idea to do this by other ways?
Thanks

Comment: Usually this is best handled inside a stored procedure

Comment: Some improvements possible there i think; you download data into a dataset, then instead of looking at the dataset, you start pulling data out of the datareader?! also, i'm not sure i understood the logic of incrementing something, then checking if its less than 0 and if it is, incrementing it again? why not just increment it by enough first time to get it past 0? (If you have -5 and you add 3, then check, then add 3 again.. you should have just added 6 the first time!)

Comment: thanks for your fast reply ,i dont know but maybe there way to temporary or something that  execute the update statement and make if condition and check value and if true complete the code and if false stop the Processes and do nothing  to original table

Comment: @CaiusJard i dont wanna make the quantity get less than i have already in the store , EX- take 5 pencil from store than i have only 3 in stock ,it showing message say you take quantity more than that in the store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a stored procedure to your database like this one

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [UpdateIfQuantityOK]
    @quantity integer,
    @ids integer
AS
    declare @sum integer

    select @sum = Sum(QUNT) 
    from store 
    where ids = @ids

    if @sum - @quantity >= 0 
    begin
        update Store 
        set Qunt = Qunt - @quantity 
        where IDS = @ids
    end
```

This stored procedure first gets the quantity available then executes the update only if the remaining quantity is bigger or equal to zero. If this is not the case then the stored procedure doesn't execute the update. To discover if the stored procedure has done the update or not you could check the return value from `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Of course, you don't need to use a `SqlDataAdapter` for this. Just a `SqlCommand` - a lot simpler and shorter to write.

```
Dim cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateIfQuantityOK", con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(N_Qunt1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ids", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox2.SelectedValue)

Dim rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
if rowsUpdated <= 0 Then
   MessageBox.Show("Not enough quantity available")
Else
   ....
End if
```

Notice also that I have changed the `AddWithValue` to a more safe `Add`. `AddWithValue` is well known to have many problems and drawbacks

[Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: you are savior , i only have basic thing about SQL i found missing (,) in Stored Procedure ' @ quantity integer
@ ids integer  ' else work great 
the code in vb changed to  ' If (rowsUpdated <= 0) ' and work as magic thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler way to update stock but be sure to stay above 0:

```
UPDATE store SET qunt = qunt - @n_qunt1 WHERE ids = @cb1 AND qunt >= @n_qunt
```

This query will affect 0 rows for only 2 reasons: there isn't enough qunt in the store, or the ids is completely wrong. Ids cannot be wrong because it came from a combo that was presumably populated with valid ids values, which means if this query updates 0 rows then there was insufficient qunt

If the query affects 1 row, the requested qunt was deducted

This query replaces your first update; you can then bin the rest of the code and just check the return value of ExecuteNonQuery, like Steve does..

Comment: thank you sir , i tried your method in SQL and did work fine but in vb when i make  `If checker.HasRows Then` it always return 0 even the value have row in SQL

Comment: `Dim ADP = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(UPDATE store SET qunt = qunt - @n_qunt1 WHERE ids = @cb1 AND qunt >= @n_qunt1, connection)
            ADP.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@N_Qunt1", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToSingle(N_Qunt1.Text)
            ADP.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@cb1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox2.SelectedValue)
            checker = ADP.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            If checker.HasRows Then
                MsgBox("0")

            Else
                MsgBox("1")
            End If`

Comment: always return **"1"**

Comment: You wouldn't use `ExecuteReader` To run an UPDATE statement, you'd use `ExecuteNonQuery` like `Dim rowsAffected as Integer = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` - now rowsAffected will be 0 or 1, if 0 then stock quantity was insufficient.